# Solr: unexpected docvalues type SORTED_SET for field '_ts' (expected=NUMERIC)

Tags: mongodb, solr

I'm trying to integrate Solr and MongoDB and I'm using

- Solr 6.1.0
- MongoDB 3.2
- Mongo-connector

following is my `schema.xml`

```
   <!-- metadata used by mongo-connector -->
   <field name="_ts" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" docValues="true"/>
   <field name="ns" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" docValues="true"/>

   <!-- some example fields for testing -->
   <field name="value" type="int" indexed="false" stored="true" docValues="true"/>
```

When I was trying to integrate Solr and Mongodb by using this command

`mongo-connector -v -m localhost:27017 -n local.abc -t http://localhost:8983/solr/test --auto-commit-interval=0 -d solr_doc_manager --unique-key=_id`

I received this error

> Exception in thread Thread-2: Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "C:\Users\tcn81hc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\mongo_connector-2.4.1.dev0-py3.5.egg\mongo_connector\util.py",
>   line 32, in wrapped
>       return f(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\tcn81hc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\mongo_connector-2.4.1.dev0-py3.5.egg\mongo_connector\doc_managers\solr_doc_manager.py",
>   line 349, in get_last_ doc
>       result = self.solr.search('*:*', sort='_ts desc', rows=1)   File "C:\Users\tcn81hc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pysolr-3.5.0-py3.5.egg\pysolr.py",
>   line 710, in search
>       response = self._select(params, handler=search_handler)   File "C:\Users\tcn81hc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pysolr-3.5.0-py3.5.egg\pysolr.py",
>   line 411, in _select
>       return self._send_request('get', path)   File "C:\Users\tcn81hc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pysolr-3.5.0-py3.5.egg\pysolr.py",
>   line 386, in _send_request
>       raise SolrError(error_message % (resp.status_code, solr_message)) pysolr.SolrError: Solr responded with an error (HTTP 500): [Reason:
>   unexpected docvalues type SORTED_SET for field '_ts'
>   (expected=NUMERIC). Use UninvertingReader or index with docvalues.]
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\tcn81hc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\threading.py",
>   line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
>       self.run()   File "C:\Users\tcn81hc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\mongo_connector-2.4.1.dev0-py3.5.egg\mongo_connector\util.py",
>   line 90, in wrapped
>       func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\tcn81hc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\mongo_connector-2.4.1.dev0-py3.5.egg\mongo_connector\oplog_manager.py",
>   line 199, in run
>       cursor, cursor_empty = self.init_cursor()   File "C:\Users\tcn81hc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\mongo_connector-2.4.1.dev0-py3.5.egg\mongo_connector\oplog_manager.py",
>   line 702, in init_cursor
>       self.checkpoint = self.rollback()   File "C:\Users\tcn81hc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\mongo_connector-2.4.1.dev0-py3.5.egg\mongo_connector\oplog_manager.py",
>   line 789, in rollback
>       last_docs.append(dm.get_last_doc())   File "C:\Users\tcn81hc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\mongo_connector-2.4.1.dev0-py3.5.egg\mongo_connector\util.py",
>   line 43, in wrapped
>       reraise(new_type, exc_value, exc_tb)   File "C:\Users\tcn81hc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\mongo_connector-2.4.1.dev0-py3.5.egg\mongo_connector\compat.py",
>   line 9, in reraise
>       raise exctype(str(value)).with_traceback(trace)   File "C:\Users\tcn81hc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\mongo_connector-2.4.1.dev0-py3.5.egg\mongo_connector\util.py",
>   line 32, in wrapped
>       return f(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\tcn81hc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\mongo_connector-2.4.1.dev0-py3.5.egg\mongo_connector\doc_managers\solr_doc_manager.py",
>   line 349, in get_last_ doc
>       result = self.solr.search('*:*', sort='_ts desc', rows=1)   File "C:\Users\tcn81hc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pysolr-3.5.0-py3.5.egg\pysolr.py",
>   line 710, in search
>       response = self._select(params, handler=search_handler)   File "C:\Users\tcn81hc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pysolr-3.5.0-py3.5.egg\pysolr.py",
>   line 411, in _select
>       return self._send_request('get', path)   File "C:\Users\tcn81hc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pysolr-3.5.0-py3.5.egg\pysolr.py",
>   line 386, in _send_request
>       raise SolrError(error_message % (resp.status_code, solr_message)) mongo_connector.errors.OperationFailed: Solr responded with an error
>   (HTTP 500): [Reason: unexpected docvalues type SORTED_SET for field
>   '_ts' (expected=NUMERIC). Use UninvertingReader or index w ith
>   docvalues.]

Comment: Do you have to set [DocValues](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DocValues)=true?

Comment: for error "unexpected docvalues type SORTED_SET ... (expected=NUMERIC)", you may refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30347597/solr-result-grouping-error-unexpected-docvalues-type-sorted-set-for-field-vend#answer-45180547)